# Is /dev/random data a psuedo-random AES cypher, and where does the entropy come from?

Tags: security, random

My current understanding of an entropy pool is that it gathers truly random *bits* of data at a slow rate.  I'd like to know how Unix & Linux collect entropy, and how that entropy is used by /dev/random.

I've heard (generically) of entropy collection methods such as the video card cpu's status when a "randomly" selected network packet arrives, matched against the hiss factor in the digital-analog converter, and other even more obtuse methods.

I believe that the entropy "pool" is tapped as need be, and is used to seed a psuedo random generator....

I'm not after an in-depth answer, but I am interested to know if this is the general approach used by Unix/Linux ?.. and perhaps some hints about  what is actually going on at the entropy-collection coal-face... and then, *what* is the entropy fed into.. Is it an AES Rijndael cipher?

The background information for my comemnts above, came from [Steve Gibson's *Security Now!* podcast: Episode #301 Going Random, Part 2 of 2](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm)... He only spoke generically (but as is his style, with enough detail and clarity so that even I could understand him. Having listened to the preceding 300 episodes helps :), ...and I'd like to know if this is how Unix/Linux does it...

Comment: Recommended reading: [Thomas Pornin's writings](http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A655+%2Brandom), especially [Howto seed the PRNG in OpenSSL properly?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3259/3262#3262) and [Is a rand from /dev/urandom secure for a login key?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/3939#3939)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Linux has two random number generators available to userspace, `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`.

`/dev/random` is a source of "true" randomness - i.e. it is not generated by a pseudo-random number generator. Entropy is fed into this by the input driver and the interrupt handler, through the functions `add_input_randomness` and `add_interrupt_randomness`. Processes reading this device will block if the entropy runs out.

`/dev/urandom` is a pseudo-random number generator. It is fed by the same entropy pool as `/dev/random`, but when that runs out, it switches to a cryptographically strong generator.

Userspace applications can feed into the entropy pool by writing to `/dev/{,u}random`.

Have a read of the [random(4)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/random.4.html) manual page, and the file [`drivers/char/random.c`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob_plain;f=drivers/char/random.c;hb=HEAD) in the kernel source tree. It is well commented and most of what you ask is explained there.

---

FreeBSD's `/dev/random` by default is a pseudo-random number generator using the Yarrow algorithm (but can point to a hardware RNG if one is connected). The software generator takes entropy from Ethernet and serial connections and hardware interrupts (changeable through `sysctl kern.random`). The Yarrow algorithm is believed to be secure as long as the internal state is unknown, therefore `/dev/random` should always output high-quality data without blocking.
See [random(4)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=random&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE).

On NetBSD, `/dev/random` provides random data based *only* on entropy collected (from disks, network, input devices, and/or tape drives; adjustable using [rndctl](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rndctl&sektion=8&manpath=NetBSD+5.1)), while `/dev/urandom` falls back to a PRNG when the entropy pool is empty, similar to Linux.
See [random(4)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=random&sektion=4&manpath=NetBSD+5.1), [rndctl(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rndctl&sektion=8&manpath=NetBSD+5.1), [rnd(9)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rnd&sektion=9&manpath=NetBSD+5.1).

OpenBSD has four generators: `/dev/random` is a hardware generator, `/dev/srandom` is a secure random data generator (using MD5 on the entropy pool: "disk and network device interrupts and such"), `/dev/urandom` is similar but falls back to a PRNG when the entropy pool is empty. The fourth, `/dev/arandom`, is also a PRNG but [using RC4](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=arc4random&sektion=3&manpath=OpenBSD+4.7).
See [random(4)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=random&sektion=4&manpath=OpenBSD+4.7), [arc4random(3)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=arc4random&sektion=3&manpath=OpenBSD+4.7).

Mac OS X also uses the Yarrow algorithm for `/dev/random`, but has an identically working `/dev/urandom` for compatibility. "Additional entropy is fed to the generator regularly by the SecurityServer daemon from random jitter measurements of the kernel." See [random(4)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/random.4.html).

Comment: Thanks. A good overview, and from the source, I see we are secure in the hands of *a Twisted Generalized Feedback Shift Register* (scary stuff :) ... Along with obtuse "random" inputs to the pool, it seems that a SHA hash is generated *"across the pool, 16 words (512 bits) at a time"* and mixed back into the pool, and then a few more gyrations are perfomed on the pool...  Steve Gibson comments in his podcast that: *SHA-256 uses/is the strongest state-of-the-art hash we have.* ... I didn't discover what generates /dev/urandom output, but the lead-up process is certainly *significant*

Comment: +1, good answer; I once tried to generate random character data with `cat /dev/random` and always wondered why my stream stopped after so many characters

Comment: @camh about `but when that runs out, it switches to a cryptographically strong generator` where and what is the source?